# Laravel 4 Migration Bug?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

You know how Laravel allows for environment based configurations? Where config files in "app/config/local" override those in "app/config". All my config files in the "local" directory override as expected, except the config file: "database.php"

I want to be able to specify different database connections for local and production environment. But when I do, and run "artisan migrate --env=local" it still attempts to use the configuration in the production folder, not the "local" folder.

Comment: have you tried `artisan migrate --env="local"`?

Comment: I believe I mentioned that in the question

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Is the migrate --env=local command trying to migrate the production database? You'll have to share the relevant contents of your database.php files to ensure there are no errors there.

Comment: @CreativityKills No, you tried `--env=local`. Did you try with it wrapped in double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sometimes get a bit confusing on local environements. I normally use the hostname in  bootstrap/start.php as opposed to the IP.

For example my Virtual Box Localhost's hostname is "debian"... just type `hostname` in your terminal to get the hostname.

This should work. However, since you're using environment config folders (which I always do) then I would remove the settings in the app/congig/* as you should never need them since your other servers will have their own settings in app/config/*yourenv*

Hope this helps

Comment: This actually helped. Turns out my MAC for some reason sets my `hostname` dynamically every time.